Need help identifying 90s movie that featured the FBI building
In the mid-to-late-1990s, I was at home watching a movie on TV. I had to turn it off before the end, thinking I'd be able to catch it again at a later day, but I never did.
Here's what I remember. Something happened, and the main characters had to go to the J. Edgar Hoover building. There was a shot of the outside of the building, as the characters, in SUVs, went into an underground garage.
I know it's not much to go on. I tried finding movies from the 90s that featured the FBI building, but had very little luck. I want to say the movie was on TV around the same time the movie Ransom was hitting HBO.
I know what I gave you is like finding a needle in a stack of needles, but I have faith! Thanks all!

Doesn't Arlington Road end in that garage? But it's very late 90s (1999).

That may be it. I need to watch the movie to know for sure.

This isn't an answer to your question, as I was going to suggest "Arlington Road" myself, but a suggestion re how to get an answer. I apologize if it's inappropriate, but here goes: I'm a long-time member/user of IMDb, the International Movie Database. (Television is equally covered there, despite its name.) It has a message board called I Need to Know, where questions such as yours can be asked. The longest I've had to "wait" for a correct reply was 20 minutes; an answer within seconds isn't uncommon, as it's a very active site. I suppose this information belongs either in a more general lo

@user131633 Welcome! While what you say may be quite true, it's hardly appropriate to come to another site and say "oh, you should go to [site x] to ask your question". As a long-time user of the IMDb Boards, I doubt you'd like it if someone told you to come here for your questions.

@Catija Well, I wouldn't have problem with all the ID questions wandering off to that place. ;-)

When I read the question I immediately thought of Arlington Road as well.

Could this movie have been Arlington Road with Jeff Bridges?  There's a scene in that movie when cars are all training into the underground garage, and there's a bomb in one of the cars, and when it goes off - it just breaks the structure in half. This movie was out in 1999. Ransom was 96/97.  I'm leaving this here, because the scene is basically exactly what you're talking about.  But Arlington Road would NOT have been on TV in the late 90s.  Hope that helps.
